# Why would this creature have a head?

Tags: creature-design, mythical-creatures, anatomy

The creature is a soft-bodied animal roughly the size of a human, that resembles a wing-less bird in its stance. It has no neck or eyes, and its mouth is at the end of a pharynx attached to the torso. Physiologically, it is similar to velvet worms, but with a vertebrate-like circulatory system. It has a brain which exists in the head. The creature has existed in some form for long enough that if the head had no use, it would be lost through natural selection. So, what features could the head have that would make it better to have than to not, and thus would prevent evolution from removing it?

Rough Diagram
[image: Why Head?]

Comment: How does it eat? Does it have to reposition its entire body to take bites?

Comment: It can reach the ground with its pharynx, allowing it to eat while standing

Comment: You said the brain is in the head. Isn't that a good enough reason to keep the head?

Comment: It would help if you drew a rough sketch of the creature.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica There would be a constant selective pressure to shrink the head and push the brain back to protect it, unless there was some sort of feature that required a head with a brain to work optimally

Comment: @Ichthys King half of its body then?

Comment: Difficult to say...as far as I know, no lineage that has evolved a head has evolved away its head. They diverged from creatures without heads diverged long ago. The issue is that things don't evolve away just because they have no use. They evolve away because they are detrimental, and so EVERYTHING in the head as well as the head itself would have to be detrimental in some way. The head is part of the basic body plan and body plans tend not to change in large groups of animals, let alone just one animal. If there was one with such a drastic change in bodyplan, expect to see many others.

Comment: Joining on the request of some drawing - This sounds very intriguing, butI can't understand how a creature could at the same time be "similar to [velvet worms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onychophora)" (which crawl like a caterpillar or slug, I think?), have a "wing-less bird's stance" (so, bipedal? but is it like a velociraptor, an ostrich, a dodo or a penguin? they are all *flightless* but winged to an extent), or have a head but "no neck" and also have a phyrynx growing from its torso (a velvet worm doesn't have a torso, right? and where do the head attach to the body?)

Comment: @DKNguyen Arachnids and crabs have lost their heads in a way, and heads will be detrimental because they stick out in front of the animal, where they are easy to strike

Comment: @IchthysKing I guess those are the closest examples, but I don't think their heads were ever very distinct from their bodies the same way tetrapods have necks. Eurypterids and their descendents, scorpions, arachnids, lobsters and shrimp never seemed to have a mammal-like neck or a very distinct head to begin with. Only insects seem to.

Comment: What is a "head"? A container for the brain? A protuberance at one end of the body? A counterweight? What makes it distinct? Why can't we call it a tail, for instance?

Comment: @nzaman The head is a structure containing the brain that sits in front of the pharynx

Comment: From the diagram, the head appears to be independent of the pharynx. Are they supposed to be connected? If the primary function is to contain the brain, then perhaps its existence is due to the combination of armour plating and heat dissipation, as in vertebrates. The heavy bone structure encapsulating the brain would limit movement in the torso, and the brain needs to lose heat, so the brain pan needs to be outside the main body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sexual desires**

Why do male peacocks have such big and colourful feathers? Or human females (large) breasts at all times? Why do stags grow horns for mating season?

There are a lot of body parts with functions that aren't useful or have a usefulness that could've been implemented in a better way. Their main function is to signal sexual availability and virility.

The head of your creature might just be something left over because it because a desirable trait in both males and females. Although wyes might still adorn it for the ability to look around and still have ears for example, these could be transferred to more specialised parts of the body. The main reason it's still there is because the creatures only reproduce with the creatures that have beautiful heads.

Answer (score 6):

Animals have heads because once they develop a nervous system, the optimizations and efficiencies of ever-larger nervous systems tend to put one major node somewhere. Everything else attaches there (or fans out from it, tree-style).

This is usually at the end of an organism, somewhere defensible. All the major sensory organs will migrate there if they didn't first show up (it's the place with the highest bandwidth in the whole organism).

A mouth or nose may not show up on this head, there are other plausible locations for those things (unless the general architecture of the creature strongly implies putting those there as well).

You will end up with a head. You won't have an easy time explaining the lack of one either if that's your goal. The head can change shape certainly, it can migrate down into the torso so that any neck is vestigial (to armor things up perhaps), but it just won't go away.

This isn't even a bilateral symmetry thing. One would expect similar from a radially symmetrical organism.

Comment: But why would the brain be in the head, rather than in the body as in arachnids?

Comment: @IchthysKing because in arachnids the head and thorax fused together in what's known as a cephalothorax.crustaceans also have this trait.

Comment: @IchthysKing an organism wants the primary sensors to be in close proximity to the processing so that they have tighter feedback on the flight or fight. Things that affect if an organism lives or dies, eats or starves.

Comment: @GaultDrakkor Though, you can kind of argue that for actuators as well. Hence, I introduce you to the perfect lifeform: the octopus.